# iOS SwiftHTTP library: Posting text and Uploading images do not work properly

Tags: ios, swift, http, http-post, multipartform-data

I just gave a try of using the iOS library [SwiftHTTP](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) for posting text and uploading images same time, but I got server errors (built in sails.js with skipper). Below is my code:

```
var questionObj: [String: AnyObject] = [
                "title": self.titleTextField.text!,
                "content": self.contentTextView.text,
                "tags": self.tagsTextField.text!,
                "images": [Upload]() // to be populated below
            ]

var images: [Upload] = []
for i in 0..<self.selectedImageData.count { 
// selectedImageData is an array of NSData from UIImage
           images.append(Upload(data: self.selectedImageData[i], fileName: "image\(i).png", mimeType: "image/png"))
            }
questionObj["images"] = images // assign the array of Upload
```

**Start uploading and posting**:

```
do {
                let opt = try HTTP.POST(targetURL, parameters: questionObj, headers: headers)
                print("starting to POST question object to remote server")
                opt.progress = {progress in
                    print("progress: \(progress)")
                }
                opt.start { response in
                    print("response from server: \(response)")
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("got an error creating the request: \(error)")
            }
```

**The above code works only if I don't upload images**.

**The following code works for me using Alamofire and multipartFormData for posting text and uploading multiple images same time**:

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, targetURL, headers: headers, multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) -> Void in

                for (key, val) in questionObj {
                    print("iterating key-val: \(key): \(val) in question JSON")
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: String(val).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name: key)
                }

                for i in 0..<self.selectedImageData.count {
                    let img = self.selectedImageData[i] // array of NSData from UIImage
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: img, name: "images", fileName: "file\(i).png", mimeType: "image/png")
                }

                }, encodingCompletion: { (encodingResult) -> Void in
                    switch encodingResult {
                    case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                        upload.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
                            print("successful response: \(response)")
                        })

                    case .Failure(let error):
                        print("in encoding completion, error: \(error)")
                    }
            })
```

I guess the reason why `SwiftHTTP` does not work for me is it does not compose a multipart form for posting and uploading the same time, but I could be wrong, as I just started learning to use `SwiftHTTP`. Thanks!

Comment: based on the docs itself, i think should  specify full path of the file in NSURL format. UIImage is type of NSObject

Comment: SwiftHTTP also supports `NSData` for their `Upload` object. See the last `public convenient init()` at https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP/blob/master/Source/Upload.swift